# How can I make an alert with the number of the buttons that are not checked?

Tags: javascript

I have n radio buttons within an HTML form. A dialog box appears if not all of them are checked. How can I make an alert with the number of the buttons that are not checked?

```
            <tr>
                <td><strong>a</strong></td>
                <td><input type="radio" id="RadioButton" name="a"/></td>
                <td><input type="radio" id="RadioButton" name="a"/></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><strong>acronym</strong></td>
                <td><input type="radio" id="RadioButton" name="acronym"/></td>
                <td><input type="radio" id="RadioButton" name="acronym"/></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><strong>blockquote</strong></td>
                <td><input type="radio" id="RadioButton" name="blockquote"/></td>
                <td><input type="radio" id="RadioButton" name="blockquote"/></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><strong>br</strong></td>
                <td><input type="radio" id="RadioButton" name="br"/></td>
                <td><input type="radio" id="RadioButton"name="br"/></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><strong>div</strong></td>
                <td><input type="radio" id="RadioButton" name="div"/></td>
                <td><input type="radio" id="RadioButton" name="div"/></td>
            </tr>
```

I want to display the number of the radios that are not checked

Comment: Please provide some code

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Perhaps you can add more details, to explain better the most important parts of your question and show a part of your data. Have a read of [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more information.

Comment: edited with code

Answer (score 0):

Use `.reduce` to identify all radio names, then use `.filter` over each name and :checked selector to figure out the number of unchecked radio fields:

```js
const allRadioNames = [...document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]')]
  .reduce((names, { name }) => {
    if (!names.includes(name)) names.push(name);
    return names;
  }, []);

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const checkedCount = allRadioNames.filter(name => {
    return document.querySelector(`input[type="radio"][name="${name}"]:checked`);
  }).length;
  
  console.log('uncheckedCount: ' + (allRadioNames.length - checkedCount));
});
```

```html
<tr>
  <td><strong>a</strong></td>
  <td><input type="radio" id="RadioButton" name="a" /></td>
  <td><input type="radio" id="RadioButton" name="a" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td><strong>acronym</strong></td>
  <td><input type="radio" id="RadioButton" name="acronym" /></td>
  <td><input type="radio" id="RadioButton" name="acronym" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td><strong>blockquote</strong></td>
  <td><input type="radio" id="RadioButton" name="blockquote" /></td>
  <td><input type="radio" id="RadioButton" name="blockquote" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td><strong>br</strong></td>
  <td><input type="radio" id="RadioButton" name="br" /></td>
  <td><input type="radio" id="RadioButton" name="br" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td><strong>div</strong></td>
  <td><input type="radio" id="RadioButton" name="div" /></td>
  <td><input type="radio" id="RadioButton" name="div" /></td>
</tr>
<br>
<button>submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: this solution will fetch the number of boxes checked but will not match by name. As long as you know how may boxes should be checked, it shouldn't be a problem. The browser allows only one of the boxes with matching names to be checked. Let me know if you need something more specific.

This is a single-line solution. Simply use a query selector all within the confines of the table. Fetch `:checked` boxes and then `alert` the length.

```js
function init() {
  var table = document.getElementById('table');
  var radioBoxes = table.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]:checked')
  alert(radioBoxes.length)
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td><strong>a</strong></td>
    <td><input type="radio" id="RadioButton" name="a" /></td>
    <td><input type="radio" id="RadioButton" name="a" /></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><strong>acronym</strong></td>
    <td><input type="radio" id="RadioButton" name="acronym" /></td>
    <td><input type="radio" id="RadioButton" name="acronym" /></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><strong>blockquote</strong></td>
    <td><input type="radio" id="RadioButton" name="blockquote" /></td>
    <td><input type="radio" id="RadioButton" name="blockquote" /></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><strong>br</strong></td>
    <td><input type="radio" id="RadioButton" name="br" /></td>
    <td><input type="radio" id="RadioButton" name="br" /></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><strong>div</strong></td>
    <td><input type="radio" id="RadioButton" name="div" /></td>
    <td><input type="radio" id="RadioButton" name="div" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<input type="button" onclick="init()" id="button" value="How many are checked?">
```